# Conditional return type based on the function header

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the following declarations:

```
interface Config {
   //...
}

type RequestConfig<T = any> = string | Config | Promise<T>;

const getData = <T = any, R = any>(cfg: RequestConfig<R>) => {
   //...
}
```

This function returns a `Promise<T>` if the `cfg` parameter is of type `string`; otherwise it returns `Promise<R>`.

I would like to describe the return type using TypeScript. The closer I've come is with:

```
const getData = 
   <T = any, R extends RequestConfig = any>(cfg: R):
      R extends Promise<infer U> ? Promise<U> : Promise<T>=> {
      //...
  }
```

The following calls are correctly typed:

```
const d2 = getData(new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => { resolve(5);})); // Promise<number>
const d3 = getData("bla"); // Promise<any>
```

However, the following is not being typed to `Promise<boolean>`; instead, it is typed as `Promise<{}> | Promise<boolean>`:

```
const d1 = getData<boolean>("something"); // `Promise<{}> | Promise<boolean>
```

How can I correctly type the return value?

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes. Sorry, that was a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to do this

```
interface Config {
  //...
}

function getData<T = any>(cfg: string): Promise<T>
function getData<T>(cfg: Promise<T>): Promise<T>
function getData<T = any, R = any>(cfg: Config): Promise<R>
function getData() {
  // your code
  return Promise.resolve()
}

const d1 = getData<boolean>("something"); // Promise<boolean>
const d2 = getData(new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => { resolve(5);})); // Promise<number>
const d3 = getData("bla"); // Promise<any>
```

hope this can help you